# Visual Studio for Mac can't deploy to compatible android emulator

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio for Mac.  When I try to build the Android project, I get the following error message.

"You are deploying an app supporting `armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86` ABIs to an incompatible device of ABI `armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86`. You should either create an emulator matching one of your app's ABIs or add `armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86` to the list of ABIs your app builds for."

This message claims the mobile app supports `armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86`.  The message also claims that the device ABI is `armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86`.

These are the same.  How can they be unsupported, since they are the same?

I am not able to deploy to any emulator configuration.

I have seen some apparently related ABI questions, but none of them are related to `Xamarin`.  Since this is all happening within the context of Xamarin and Visual Studio for Mac, any solution needs to be specific to that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to solve this by reading [this MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=macos).

I had to double click on the android project to open the properties, click android build, and select all architectures listed under the advanced tab.  As far as I can tell this has no ramifications on the build other than it works now.

Comment: Transitioning to Xamarin from native development (hopefully for a one time project) and I swear, Xamarin tooling is full of gotchas and arcane workarounds that I sometimes wonder if anyone at MS is actually paying attention to developer comfort.

Comment: I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2019 for Windows and that solution also worked for me. I noticed that `armeabi` is no longer available as an option, maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows. With Visual Studio 2019:
Right click on your project and Properties -> Android Option -> Advanced (Button srolling down).
There select de Supported architectures and marck that ones you will need.